# List(s) of common anglicisms, rusisms, and other -isms?

Tags: word-usage, resources, style

Are there lists of common words and idioms that native speakers of
particular languages often get wrong or try to translate literally,
preferably with native alternatives?  Something like this would be nice
to have when you edit your or someone else's texts before publishing
them.  I'm particularly interested in anglicisms and rusisms, but any
list would be nice to have.

Answer (score 3):

I have noticed at least following mistakes or bad habits English speakers do or have:

- use of *ĝi* as a formal subject: It rains → **Ĝi pluvas**
- overuse of participles in an effort to express continuous aspect of English verbs: I am doing → *Mi estas faranta* instead of the simpler *Mi faras*
- overuse of the *esti* passive in an effort to replicate the frequent use of passive in English: The work has been done → *La laboro estas farita* instead of the simpler *La laboron oni faris*
- combine the one just above with an agent structure: The work has been done by the workers → *La laboro estas farita de la laboristoj* instead of the simpler *La laboristoj faris la laboron*
- combine all above to an overwhelmingly complex and erroneous sentence: The work was being done by the workers, when it began to rain → *-*La laboro estis farata de la laboristoj, kiam ĝi komencis pluvi** instead of the simpler *Dum la laboristoj laboris, komencis pluvi*

Comment: In the examples, instead of "la laboro estas **farinta** de la laboristoj" it should be "la laboro estas **farita** de la laboristoj". The same correction applies to all the examples you used with "la laboro estas/estis...".

Comment: Ofc, see, this happens when I try to speak as complex as some :-)